# How much market shares OpenGL2.0 in iPhone os hardwares(iPhone/iPod Touch)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm planning making a game for AppStore, so I'm studying GLES.
But, GLES 1.1 and 2.0 APIs are different about handling in some features.(and limitations)
I have not enough time to consider both of them, I have to choosing one.

2.0 is clearly better in developer's view, but I'm worry about it's market share. I wish most users moved on newer SGX based hardware, but in fact, I don't know. Does anybody have information about location of those hardware ratio data in iPhone OS supported hardwares? (iPhone/iPod touch, per GPU) Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 3GS, 3rd Gen iPod Touch, and iPad all support OpenGL ES 2.0.

[AdMob's March 2010 mobile metrics report](http://metrics.admob.com/2010/04/march-2010-mobile-metrics-report/) has a breakdown of usage by iPhone OS model. iPhone 3GSs generated 39% of traffic and 3rd Gen iPod generated 12%, so about 51% of iPhone OS devices supported OpenGL ES 2.0. These data don't include the iPad and are based on usage rather than the number of devices or users.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone 3GS is the only one which has OpenGL ES 2.0 chip. iPhone, iPhone 3G and all the iPods have OpenGL ES 1.1 chip.

I guess only Apple has the exact figures about how many of each of these devices Apple has sold. But most definitely most of the devices have OpenGL ES 1.1. You can also get OpenGL ES 1.1 context on iPhone 3GS. So, by choosing 1.1 you can target all the devices and by choosing 2.0 you can only support iPhone 3GS.

I would choose 1.1. The second alternative would be to build separate rendering engines for for 1.1 and 2.0 and to select one to be used at runtime. But most definitely I wouldn't target OpenGL ES 2.0 only.

Comment: The latest (third-generation) iPod touch also supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I wonder why forgot that. But this doesn't change my opinion. I would still go with 1.1.